# Ruby 3.2 Upgrade, therubyracer gem cant bundle

Tags: ruby, therubyracer

I'm currently upgrading the Ruby version in my application to 3.2 and I'm having an issue with `therubyracer` not being able to bundle.

Is this gem compatible with ruby 3.2?

Theres not much to go off in the logs:

```
#35 229.4 /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
#35 229.4 `process_queue'
#35 229.4 /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2
#35 229.4 levels) in create_threads'
#35 229.4
#35 229.4 An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.3), and Bundler cannot
#35 229.4 continue.
#35 229.4
#35 229.4 In Gemfile:
#35 229.4   therubyracer
```

Comment: Some of the older JavaScript packagers aren't compatible with Ruby 3.0, but the good news is they're no longer necessary with newer Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem [therubyracer](https://github.com/rubyjs/therubyracer) is no longer being maintained ([see related issue](https://github.com/rubyjs/therubyracer/issues/462)).

[mini_racer](https://github.com/rubyjs/mini_racer) might contain the functionality you need